# Слово «прощай» — какая часть речи?

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи

**Прощай, прощай, бедный листопадничек!**
Какой частью речи (глаголом или междометием) является слово "прощай" в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Это этикетная формула. Из предложенных вариантов верным будет **междометие.**

А вообще, в отечественном языкознании имеется как минимум три точки зрения на определение частеречной принадлежности, статуса данной лексической группы.

Грамматическая разнородность языковых явлений, представляющих собою этикетные формулы, позволила некоторым ученым относить слова здравствуйте, спасибо, пожалуйста к тем, "которые до настоящего времени остаются практически вне квалификации их как частей речи" (А. И. Германович, Д. Э. Розенталь, Л. Д. Чеснокова и др).

Другая точка зрения связана с такими именами, как В. В. Виноградов, Р. Н. Панов, Н. М. Шанский, Н. А. Германов и др. Эти ученые считают этикетные слова и выражения одной из групп междометий и представляют ее либо отдельной семантической группой, наряду с эмоциональными и императивными междометиями (В. В. Виноградов, Н. М. Шанский, Н. А. Германов и др.), либо рассматривают ее в составе эмоциональных междометий (Р. Н. Панов, Н. С. Валгина и др.).

Третьей точки зрения придерживаются ученые, рассматривающие эти речевые формулы как частицы (А. А. Зализняк, В. В. Морковкин и др.).

Comment: _Людмила: Третьей точки зрения придерживаются ученые, рассматривающие эти речевые формулы как частицы (А. А. Зализняк, В. В. Морковкин и др.)._ === С др. согласен (так, к примеру, у Кузнецова в БТС). А вот Зализняк (в "Грамматическом словаре...", 2006) и Морковкин (в "Большом универсальном словаре русского языка", 2016) слово _прощай_  считают междометием. Не частицей.

Comment: Так я же о всей группе этикетных выражений. В некоторых словарях и слово прощай считают частицей, в энциклопедическом, например: https://slovar.cc/enc/slovar/1774405.html

Comment: Если рассматривать слово "прощай" в качестве междометия, то что будет являться граматической основой этой синтаксической конструкции?

Comment: Это  нечленимое вокативное предложение, осложнённое междометием (как "Ах, мама!"), выражает эмоциональную  реакцию говорящего на ситуацию - грусть прощания с листопадничком. Слова-предложения представляют собой особый структурный тип и не могут быть отнесены ни к двусоставным предложениям, ни к односоставным. Они не имеют отдельных членов предложения и не выполняют номинативной функции, так как ничего не называют. https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/280-slova-predlogeniya.html